# Marmalade deployment to android: Icon and caption settings have no effect

Tags: android, deployment, icons, caption, marmalade

I am working with Marmalade for mobile development, and want to define custom icons and of course a custom name (called "caption" in Marmalade) to be displayed on the phone when the application is deployed.

I have read http://docs.madewithmarmalade.com/display/MD74/Configuring+deployment+settings+in+MKBs#ConfiguringdeploymentsettingsinMKBs-Genericdeploymentsettings, which outlines some of the deployment options in Marmalade, as well as http://api.madewithmarmalade.com/deployment_options_hub_deploy_tool_.html, a complete overview of deployment options.

So, according to the first link, I need to specify `icon` and `caption` options in my mkb. I have done this, see mkb here:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env mkb
files
{
    s3eWebViewBasic.cpp
}

subprojects
{
    ExamplesMain
    s3eWebView
}

assets
{
    (data)
    page1.html
    s3eWebView.js
    login.html
    page1.css
    boilerplate.css
    hello.css
    img/image.jpg
    [win32_assets]
    <include WebView32Assets>
}


deployments
{
    icon=data/img/icon.png
    caption="MyName"
    [Windows]
    assets=win32_assets
}
```

However, on my phone, I still only see the default icon and default caption, not the ones I have provided.

The icon exists at the folder specified in the mkb, and is of size 339 x 303. However, according to the first link above, size shouldn't matter anyway, since ImageMagick automatically resizes the icon for the device deployed to.

I am deploying via Marmalade Hub, to my android, using the configuration setting: android (default).

This happens whether I deploy the debug build or the release build.

Why are my settings not being used for the caption and the icon?

This is the deployment output, from Marmalade Hub:

> ```
> Deploying: android  WARNING: file already exists in deployment: deployments\default\android\release\arm\intermediate_files\assets\s3eWebView.js
> ```
>
> SUCCESS (WITH WARNINGS): Package written to
>   'C:\Marmalade\7.3\examples\s3e\s3eWebViewBasic\build_s3ewebviewbasic_vc12x\deployments\default\android\release\arm'
>   [took 8.35s]  SUCCESS (WITH WARNINGS): S3E package deployed to device
>   [took 13.98s]

Thanks and best regards,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Hub to deploy to Android you need to set the options within the Configuration settings.  The default is to chose the 'default' options, which is what I think you are seeing.

From the Hub Project screen, select either 'Create' or 'Edit current' from the Configuration drop down.  Icon settings can be found on the 'Basic' tab and the caption setting is on the 'Project Tab'

Answer (score 0):

The application name and icons are taken from `AndroidManifest.xml`. Check if you have provided a custom manifest or not. I do not favor using Hub yet, since its functionality keep tricking me. You can also try using the old way of deploying using `deploy tool`. It always works fine.